# Calculate Size of Hexagons to Fit Inside Rectangle

Tags: wpf, vb.net, math

I will need to put a dynamic number of hexagons (28 in this example) inside a "rectangle" aka user's screen size (2000px width, 1000px height in this example). I wish to offset every other column. There will be a percentage margin.

I attempted to create a custom panel, my code is below:

```
Protected Overrides Function MeasureOverride(ByVal availableSize As Size) As Size
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim side As Double = ((((Me.ActualHeight * 2) + (Me.ActualWidth * 2)) / 6) - Me.InternalChildren.Count) / 6
    Dim w As Double = 2 * side
    Dim h As Double = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    For Each child As FrameworkElement In InternalChildren
        Dim childMaxSize = New Size(w, h)
        child.Measure(childMaxSize)
    Next

    Return availableSize
End Function

Protected Overrides Function ArrangeOverride(ByVal finalSize As Size) As Size
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim side As Double = ((((Me.ActualHeight * 2) + (Me.ActualWidth * 2)) / 6) - Me.InternalChildren.Count) / 6
    Dim w As Double = 2 * side
    Dim h As Double = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    Dim x As Double = 0
    Dim y As Double = 0
    Dim shift As Boolean = True
    Dim shiftOffset As Double

    Dim offsetChild As FrameworkElement = TryCast(InternalChildren(0), FrameworkElement)
    shiftOffset = h / 2

    For i As Integer = 0 To InternalChildren.Count - 1 'For Each child As FrameworkElement In Me.InternalChildren
        Dim child As FrameworkElement = TryCast(InternalChildren(i), FrameworkElement)
        child.Margin = New Thickness(side * 0.02)

        If child IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim finalY As Double = y

            If shift Then finalY += shiftOffset

            shift = Not shift
            child.Arrange(New Rect(New Point(x, finalY), New Size(w, h)))

            x += w * 0.75
            Dim nextWidth As Double = 0

            If i + 1 < InternalChildren.Count Then nextWidth = w

            If x + nextWidth > Me.ActualWidth Then
                shift = True
                x = 0
                y += h
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return finalSize
End Function
End Class
```

My issue is trying to calculate the side. I am close, but it doesn't seem to fit quite right in the "rectangle", or perhaps there is something else I'm not getting.

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!

EDIT:
To explain a little differently - my formula works if I don't offset every other hexagon column (tested). I'm pretty sure my root issue is that my code is measuring the size each hexagon needs to be in order to fit in the specified rectangle before placing them. However, after they are placed and then offset, I'm finding the hexagons appearing out of the rectangle. Oh also my hexagons are flat-topped. Thanks!
Pictures are below - top is what I need, bottom is what I'm getting.
The red is the area the hexagons need to fit in:

[image: want]
[image: have]

EDIT 2:
I attempted MBo's suggestion of side = side - offset (my offset is height * 0.5). It appears to make the hexagons too small:

```
Protected Overrides Function MeasureOverride(ByVal availableSize As Size) As Size
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim side As Double = ((((Me.ActualHeight * 2) + (Me.ActualWidth * 2)) / 6) - Me.InternalChildren.Count) / 6
    Dim h As Double = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    'new
    side = side - (h * 0.5)
    h = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    Dim w As Double = 2 * side

    For Each child As FrameworkElement In InternalChildren
        Dim childMaxSize = New Size(w, h)
        child.Measure(childMaxSize)
    Next

    Return availableSize
End Function

Protected Overrides Function ArrangeOverride(ByVal finalSize As Size) As Size
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim side As Double = ((((Me.ActualHeight * 2) + (Me.ActualWidth * 2)) / 6) - Me.InternalChildren.Count) / 6
    Dim h As Double = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    'new
    side = side - (h * 0.5)
    h = side * Math.Sqrt(3.0)

    Dim w As Double = 2 * side
```

Comment: Could you attach a picture showing what's happens wrong?

Comment: What is given? What is goal parameter? It seems that if you seek for edge size, and your formula works without offset, then you have to ignore offset, find size, and just subtract offset to get final edge size.

Comment: I have thought of this, but what would I subtract the offset from? The individual height, weight, or both? I'm not sure what you mean by goal perimeter - do you mean of the rectangle? In this case it would be 2(1000 + 2000) which is what I have going on in the first part of calculating the 'side' double.

Comment: Not perimeter - parameter. I've considered hex edge length A as value to be found. If you calculated that you can place N hexagons with edge A in given rectangle, and want to make offset with width F, you have to make hexagons with A'=A-F

Comment: I added a second edit to my question. It appears to make the hexagons too small. I think A=A-F is taking off too much off the size of the side.

Comment: Emmm.. What is your offset? What is height? I thought that offset is small light-red space between hexagons (honeycomb walls)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry no that's the percentage margin I was talking about at the beginning of my question. The height is calculated by side * Math.Sqrt(3.0), the offset is height * 0.5, and the margin is calculated by side * 0.02.

Comment: OK. So my answer still valid, just rotated by 90.

Comment: Edit added for your configuration (not using margins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider bounding box size for dense hexagonal grid with R rows, C columns, vertical hexagons orientation (pointy topped, two vertical edges), edge size A:
[image]

```
Height = A/2 * (3 * R + 1)
```

Width depends on configuration:

Odd and even rows with the same number C of hexagons (N=R*C):

```
Width = A * Sqrt(3)/2 * (2 * C + 1)
E E E E
 O O O O
E E E E
 O O O O
```

Odd rows are shorter with C-1 hexagons (also R=1 case) (N~R*(C-1/2)):

```
Width = A * Sqrt(3) * C
E E E E
 O O O
E E E E
```

Could you apply these formulas to fit needed number N of hexes into predefined box WxH?

You probably need also to consider some factorisations of N (or slightly larger number) into R, C factors to minimize empty space (for example, `38=2x19` is not suitable for near-square regions, but `40=5x8` or `42=6x7` could be better)

**Edit**
For your configuration - flat-topped, first column  is lower than second:

```
BoundWidth = Side/2 * (3 * C + 1)
BoundHeight = Side * Sqrt(3)/2 * (2 + R) = Height * (R/2 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I edited my question at the bottom to be worded more clearly. I'm going to try your advice, but I would like all the hexagons to be the same size. I don't really care about the odd whitespace, I just need them to fit the best they can. Thanks again!